# Customising Notification UI

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I am working on the Customising Remote Notification UI where I want to add 4 `UNNotificationAction`. 
I am done with the implementation and it is working fine on all devices except **iPhone 5**. On iPhone 5 it shows only first 2 actions and Clear action which is default one.

And also code inside my Content Extension and Service Extension is not called on iPhone 5.

Below is my code snippet.

```
func setCategories(){
        //Actions
        let remindLaterAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "remindLater", title: "Remind me later", options: UNNotificationActionOptions(rawValue: 0))
        let acceptAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "accept", title: "Accept", options: .foreground)
        let declineAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "decline", title: "Decline", options: .destructive)
        let commentAction = UNTextInputNotificationAction(identifier: "comment", title: "Comment", options: .authenticationRequired, textInputButtonTitle: "Send", textInputPlaceholder: "Share your thoughts..")

        //Category
        let invitationCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "alarm.category", actions: [remindLaterAction, acceptAction, declineAction, commentAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: UNNotificationCategoryOptions(rawValue: 0))

        //Register the app’s notification types and the custom actions that they support.
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([invitationCategory])
    }
```

Is it related to the device or OS please suggest.

Comment: It is related to the device, it has to support 3D touch.

Comment: But can I customise Notification UI and it can reflect on iPhone 5?

Comment: You can customize the notification UI. However, you cannot interact with it.